# Laravel 5.5 : Dynamically change throttle time

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.5, throttling

Currently i am working on login throttle, I have to change the throttle time on 2nd throttle dynamically.

How will i be able to do that ?

Comment: No. throttle delay is value of `decayMinutes` or `1` otherwise.

Comment: Oops, How ... i am. sorry for the mistake. But how will i be able to alter it dynamically ? @MarcinOrlowski

Answer (score 1):

Middleware (such as `throttle`) can be [defined inside controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/controllers#controller-middleware) as well.

A solution would be to conditionally set the middleware in the controllers' constructor, something along the lines of:

```
if (true) {
    $this->middleware('throttle:60,1');
} else {
    $this->middleware('throttle:30,1');
}
```

In Laravel 5.6, here’s how you specify a User model attribute used to determine the number of requests a user can make within the provided timeframe (in minutes):

```
Route::middleware('throttle:rate_limit,1');
```

See https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-6-dynamic-rate-limiting and the docs for more information.

Good luck!

Comment: But how the rest of middleware will work ? How will it change the time internally ?

Comment: You can pass parameters to the throttle middleware to specifiy the maximum rate per *x* seconds. Also, I have added a second solution to the problem for Laravel 5.6 and up.

Comment: Okay, Can you explain it a bit, Will the middleware will be a custom one ? How the middleware will set the time etc, Kindly please make your answer a bit brief, Code will be great. Can't find a way out.

Comment: The middleware is already created for you, use it as explained in the answer (i.e. `throttle`). If you want to specificy the maximum rate per *x* seconds, pass in parameters (i.e. `throttle:60,1`). Detailed information about how to apply middleware to routes can be found in the official Laravel documentation. Maybe you should just try it out and see what happens, it's not that hard.